# How can I use fit with generator on seq2seq model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to customise [this](https://github.com/aravindpai/How-to-build-own-text-summarizer-using-deep-learning/blob/master/How_to_build_own_text_summarizer_using_deep_learning.ipynb) code, because the code is not efficient for training on large datasets.

How do I use fit generator with tokenizer, the problem here is that tokenizer is already working by scanning all text data and giving out `x_train` in one go.

So it all comes down to creating generator with following snippet of code which works with entire dataset.

```
x_tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=tot_cnt-cnt) 
x_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(x_tr))

#convert text sequences into integer sequences
x_tr_seq    =   x_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_tr) 
x_val_seq   =   x_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_val)

#padding zero upto maximum length
x_tr    =   pad_sequences(x_tr_seq,  maxlen=max_text_len, padding='post')
x_val   =   pad_sequences(x_val_seq, maxlen=max_text_len, padding='post')
```

Comment: it fits in memory, so what's the problem?

Comment: @NicolasGervais if the dataset is large memory overflows

Comment: Why not change ```x_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(x_tr))``` to ```x_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_tr)```